# Creating a chart from the pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet and  I have two pivot tables. I am trying to generate two different chart for the pivot table.

I tried the below code, but I am getting an

> automation error

in the line

> .SetSourceData ptr1

Could anyone help, how I can avoid this,

Here is my code for both the charts. Also, is it possible I can have a single code, instead of tow individual codes?

```
Sub chartG702()
Dim cht As Chart
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set ptable1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set ptr1 = ptable1.TableRange2
Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=390, _
    Width:=390, _
    Top:=350, _
    Height:=250)
sh.Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
.SetSourceData ptr1
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True '<~~ Red
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "M1"
End Sub
```

I don't have any problem with the below code. this is just for reference.

```
Sub chartG70()
Dim cht As Chart
   If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1
Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=440, _
    Width:=390, _
    Top:=50, _
    Height:=250)
sh.Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
.SetSourceData ptr
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True '<~~ Red
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "M"
End Sub
```

Comment: change Set ptr1 = ptable1.TableRange2    to   Set ptr1 = ptable1.TableRange1

Comment: .TableRange2  include  pivottable's  page field.

Comment: @Dy.Lee I tried and still getting error

Comment: It works well in my sheet both  tablerange1 , tablerange2.

Comment: check your vb reference.

Comment: @Dy.Lee what should I check in VB reference

Comment: Sometimes  , vb reference  missed . I think   automation error caused by that.

Comment: OK. I will check for vb reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152539/discussion-between-jenny-and-dy-lee).

Comment: @Dy.Lee is there any other way to generate chart from the pivot table ?

Comment: @Dy.Lee the problem is not yet resolved